# Separate NSArray to a list of NSString type objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, variadic-functions

A UIActionSheet is initalized with:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2", nil];
```

I am trying to pass an NSArray into the "otherButtonTitles" message.

I tried to pass an NSArray using:

```
otherButtonTitles:[array]
```

but the message is expecting a list of NSStrings.

The only way I can think of breaking an NSArray into a set of NSStrings is to by using componentsJoinedByString but it gives me a comma separated list that is a single NSString.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow... good question! Maybe using NSInvocation this is possible somehow?

Comment: I just used the answer from a similar question to do this. It worked very well for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602214/use-nsarray-to-to-specify-otherbuttontitles

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That method takes varargs. There's not a really easy way to make the conversion your describing, and it definitely isn't worth the trouble to try in this case. This is just a convenience method.

Just use `-init` and configure everything with the accessors (`-setDelegate:`, `-addButtonWithTitle:`, `-setCancelButtonIndex:`, etc.)

Comment: See also Brad Smith's answer regarding button ordering when using the "addButtonWithTitle:" approach (but noting that you *don't* need to subclass the UIActionSheet to use this; they're all public methods): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262205/uiactionsheet-addbuttonwithtitle-doesnt-add-buttons-in-the-right-order

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [you can't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431910/is-possible-send-a-array-in-obj-c-for-a-variable-arguments-function) in Objective-C.