# IOS UIActionSheet Button behave as a CancelButton?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I'm creating an `UIActionSheet`:

`UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Choose region/city"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil

                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];`

```
for (Cities *c in self.cities) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:c.name];
}

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

I'm just setting the cities names as the buttontitle. The Cities array length is 8.
The output is fine, but when I click on the first Button ( this one is called Auckland) it says it is a CancelButton.

The other buttons and the cancelbutton works fine, only the first one not. Both the Auckland button and the `CancelButton` got a `buttonIndex` of 0.

Can anyone tell me why this is? And how to fix it?

PS:
If i do cancelButtonTitle:nil, its working fine. But i would like the Cancel button:)

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174486/problems-with-cancel-button-and-uiactionsheet?rq=1,