# Passing an NSArray as otherButtonTitles - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Currently i'm using

```
...otherButtonTitles:@"Hotel Laguna", @"Hotel Village", @"Hotel Torre", @"Hotel Baia", nil];
```

to create an `UIActionSheet`.

I would like to pass an NSArray... something like:

```
    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] 
initWithObjects:@"Hotel Laguna", @"Hotel Village", @"Hotel Torre", @"Hotel Baia", nil];

    ...otherButtonTitles:names];
```

Is this possible in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602214/use-nsarray-to-to-specify-otherbuttontitles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `otherButtonTitles` by enumerating through an array if you have objects in an array like this:

```
(NSString * title in Strings) 

{ 
[alert addButtonWithTitle:title]; 
}
```