# Add Buttons to UIActionSheet From NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I want to add buttons to a `UIActionSheet`.

```
UIActionSheet *as = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Album"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelled"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];


for (int i =0; [groups count]; i++) 
{
      [as addButtonWithTitle:[groups objectAtIndex:i]];    
}

[as showInView:self.view];
```

but the buttons are not showing.

Comment: Your code is good, and it should work fine, just check the contents of the your `groups` array, I think it's empty.

Comment: Pls check u r for loop code, for (int i =0; [groups count]; i++),loop not exit your group.conut value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try This one:

```
 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Font Name?"
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

 UIToolbar *pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
 pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
 [pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

 NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
 [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

 UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet)];
 [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,390)];//set it with your way
```

May be it will help.
happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

I ran the piece of code and it worked fine for me. Check the groups array,it is supposed to be an array of NSString objects. Try adding cancel button in the end. Refer this-->
[Use NSArray to specify otherButtonTitles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602214/use-nsarray-to-specify-otherbuttontitles)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.count; i++)
```