# Push notifications: Set arguments manually within localized strings (while app is active)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When Parse.com is sending push notifications while the app is not in the foreground, everything works just fine. Though the `loc-key` the correct localized string from `localizable.string` is found and the arguments that come through `loc-args` are filled in properly:

```
"%1$@ has created an event and sent out %2$@ invitations"
```

becomes "Frank has created an event and sent out 14 invitations."

```
"Good News: %1$@ has joined your event!"
```

becomes "Good News: Oliver has joined your event!"

when the app is in the foreground, I want to show an in-app banner as well. For that purpose I need the get the same correct string as above.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let aps: NSDictionary! = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary

    let alert: NSDictionary = aps.objectForKey("alert") as! NSDictionary

    let locArgs: NSArray = alert.objectForKey("loc-args") as! NSArray

    let locKey: String = alert.objectForKey("loc-key") as! String

    let localizedString: NSString = NSLocalizedString(locKey, comment: "")

    let localizedStringWithArgs = NSString(format: localizedString, locArgs)

    println(localizedStringWithArgs)
```

...if locArgs is

```
( Frank,
"14"
)
```

the output is:

```
(
Frank,
14
) has created an event and sent out 14 invitations.
```

when using normal placeholder like %@ or

```
(
    Frank,
    14
) has created an event and sent out (null) invitations.
```

when using %1$@, %2$@...

...how can I properly set the arguments in the same way it is done by apple when the app is inactive through filling in the loc-args in the right spots %1$@, %2$@...?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799067/1988185 for a slightly hacky workaround